# Difference between custom classes at WatchKit or WatchKit Extension?

Tags: ios, watchkit

Where is the different if I put my custom classes for the interface storyboard at the WatchKit or the WatchKist extension. (By example myInterfaceController)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only have WKInterfaceController classes in your WatchKit extension target.  You will not be allowed to have any code in your WatchKit app.  The folder that the files are doesn't really matter, what matters is what target they are in.  Make sure all WKInterfaceController classes are in the WatchKit extension target.